# "in a given factors" or "in given factors"

Tags: grammatical-number

I would like to ask about these words. Which one is grammatically correct?

"The decision will vary **in a given factors**" or "The decision will vary i**n given factors**" ?

Since the word "factors" refers to more than one thing, I  think it should be plural. I have searched in google, but  the result shows both of them exist.

thanks

Comment: It's all singular. We would use **a factor**, so we would also use **a given factor**. Perhaps your search returned results from possessive uses: **a given factor's *(something)***?

Answer (score 1):

As far as l know you can't use "a" as an article before a plural so you can't say "a books" or "a cats" , hence, you can't say "a factors" or "a given factors".

Comment: Correct. Factors is a plural form so you can’t put “a” before it.